# In my method how do i assign a specific string using an existing array?

Tags: java

I have generated a random number, converted it to a String, now I am wondering how I assign "String suit"(which is a random number converted to string) to an actual suit in the suitValues array?

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class Card
{
    int roll;
    String suit = "";
    String number = "";
    String[] numberValues = {"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K", "A"};
    String[] suitValues = {"Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs", "Spades"};
    public void createCard()
    {
        roll= 1 + (int)(Math.random() * ((4-1)+1));
        suit = Integer.toString(roll);
        roll= (int)(Math.random() * ((13-1)+1));
        number = Integer.toString(roll);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do, what's the expected output for 2 random numbers ?

Comment: im trying to use the converted random numbers to assign values to the property from the array, lets say the random # was a 2 when the method gets called I would like diamonds to be assigned to the suit property (diamonds is 2nd in the array suitValues)

Comment: Well, first of all there is no need to convert that number to a string. You created an array, an array has indexes, it begins from 0. So to "access" Diamonds, you'll actually need `1`. The syntax is as such `suitValues[1]`, let's replace the `1` with `roll` : `suitValues[roll]`. I think that you should study more, especially about arrays for now. Have fun

Answer (score 0):

```
 suit = suitValues[Math.floor(Math.random()*4)];
 number = numberValues[Math.floor(Math.random()*13)];
```

Answer (score 0):

you should declare them static class members and not as instance members.

```
static String[] numberValues = {"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K", "A"};
static String[] suitValues = {"Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs", "Spades"};
```

secondly, you have the suit property for the class card, whenever you need to know which suit it actually represents you can always check for

```
Card.suitValues[cardInstance.suit]
```

Answer (score 0):

Why would you convert the number to a `String`?

If I get you correctly, you want to assign a random value in the array `suitValues` to the variable `suit`. Then you can do this.

```
public class Card
{
    int roll;
    String suit = "";
    String number = "";
    String[] numberValues = {"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K", "A"};
    String[] suitValues = {"Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs", "Spades"};
    public void createCard()
    {
        roll= (Math.floor(Math.random())) % 4;
        suit = numberValues[roll];
        roll= (Math.floor(Math.random())) % 13;
        number = numberValues[roll];
    }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your input, Thank You.